# Android NDK, header files not found on build

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When using the Android NDK, A.cpp is my entry point.

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := A
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := A.cpp
```

However A.cpp includes other files found in subdirs.

- A.cpp includes dir1/B.cpp with the statement #include "B.cpp"
- B.cpp includes dir2/C.cpp with the statement #include "C.cpp"

This causes the includes to be not found during compile.

The only way to fix it is to change it is to add the subfolder in the statement:

```
#include "dir1/B.cpp"
```

Is there a solution without having to add the subfolder to all the statements?

Answer (score 0):

Add dir1 to the to the include path with the `-I` command line option

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I./dir1
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html): _"It is possible to specify additional include paths by writing:

`LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I<path>`,
It is better, however, to use `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` for this purpose, since doing so also makes it possible to use the paths available for native debugging with ndk-gdb."_

Comment: If you can get the gdb to work, more power to you. I gave up on that years ago